# Grails - Images in css files of plugin require different path in war than run-app

Tags: css, grails, war

I have some css and image files I would like to share between two applications. I created a plugin to do so, and the images resolve properly to their paths in the css files if I use `grails run-app`. If I create a war, though, the image paths will only resolve to http://www.mysite.com/static/plugins/myplugin-0.1/images/myimage.png instead of to http://www.mysite.com/static/images/myimage.png. This error did not occur with grails 2.2, but it is occurring with grails 2.3.1.

The plugin is installed with the following line in BuildConfig.groovy: `grails.plugin.location.'myplugin' = "../myplugin"`

Is there a setting I need to update to get wars working properly again?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the urls in my css file to use relative paths ("../images/myimage.png" instead of "/images/myimage.png"), and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Accept your own answer boss! Good that you found a solution, I thought this might be related to the resources-things which can be a real hassle.